# Proving AND distributive law using Boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

$$ X(Y+Z) = (XY) + (XZ) $$

I can’t seem to derive the proper steps to prove this equation using Boolean axioms. The hint I’ve been given is using demorgans laws proofs but I still can’t seem to figure it out.
These are the axioms I’ve been given to prove this. I know that this is typically a given axiom but I have to use the others to prove that this is true.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPdbHp-cPxgLiwXS1zP2npvK92CG-I8IPxvN52574xEs2pd_Q

Comment: Using the Boolean axioms, means that you should set up a truth table, right ?

Comment: No it means using any of these axioms to prove that both sides are equivalent https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPdbHp-cPxgLiwXS1zP2npvK92CG-I8IPxvN52574xEs2pd_Q

Comment: This is usually one of the axioms for a Boolean algebra. Since this isn't the case for you: What precisely are the axioms of a Boolean algebra that you've been given?

Comment: Then it is the distributive law

Comment: @AhmadBazzi yes it is the distributive law, but I have to prove that both sides of the equation are equivalent using only Boolean equations (not the AND distributive law) the point is to derive the equation

Comment: yeah but you sent a table with the question being one axiom. So you should prove it using all other axioms except the distributive axiom ?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can use any other axiom except the And distributive.

Comment: Can you use the Or distribution?

Comment: Yes, You can use any axiom except the AND distributive axiom itself

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the notation you use in the question.
It might not be obvious which law is each, since in the image your axioms have a different notation, but I thing with the tags in each step you'll get it.
\begin{align}
XY + XZ
&= (XY + X)(XY + Z)     \tag{distributivity}\\
&= X (XY + Z)           \tag{absorption}\\
&= X (Z + XY)           \tag{commutativity}\\
&= X ((Z + X)(Z + Y))   \tag{distributivity}\\
&= (X(Z + X))(Z + Y)    \tag{associativity}\\
&= X(Z + Y)             \tag{absorption}\\
&= X(Y + Z).            \tag{commutativity}
\end{align}
Notice you still have to pick the right law (there is a pair of each), except for the distributivity, in which case we're using here the one there we're not proving.

Comment: I'm confused on the very first step, how did you use the OR distributive law to make XY + XZ = (XY + X) (XY + Z ), maybe I just can't see it, but it looks as if you used the AND law of distributivity

Comment: @Jakemathbad Make $W=XY$, and use $W+XZ=(W+X)(W+Z)$.